# Weird XAML RenderTransform behavior (SVG)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, svg, 2d

I have svg file that I've converted to XAML using Inkscape, and something is wrong. This is what I expect:[image]

And this is what I get:

[image]

Any ideas?

SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1920" height="1080">
<rect x="51" y="37" width="198" height="99" id="rect1" style="fill-opacity:0;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);fill:rgb(255,255,255)"  />
<rect x="111" y="178" width="216" height="125" id="rect2" style="fill-opacity:0;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);fill:rgb(255,255,255)"  />
<rect x="302" y="42" width="181" height="113" id="rect3" style="fill-opacity:0;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);fill:rgb(255,255,255)"  />
<rect x="391" y="234" width="94" height="84" id="rect4" style="fill-opacity:0;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);fill:rgb(255,255,255)" transform="matrix(0.7071068,0.7071068,-0.7071068,0.7071068,323.4487,-228.8742)" />
</svg>
```

XAML generated file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
  <Canvas Name="svg6" Width="1920" Height="1080">
    <Canvas.Resources/>
    <Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="51" Canvas.Top="37" Width="198" Height="99" Name="rect1" Fill="#00FFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#000000"/>
    <Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="111" Canvas.Top="178" Width="216" Height="125" Name="rect2" Fill="#00FFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#000000"/>
    <Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="302" Canvas.Top="42" Width="181" Height="113" Name="rect3" Fill="#00FFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#000000"/>
    <Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="391" Canvas.Top="234" Width="94" Height="84" Name="rect4" Fill="#00FFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#000000">
      <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.7071068 0.7071068 -0.7071068 0.7071068 323.4487 -228.8742"/>
      </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Don't assume that well-tested, widely used code is buggy until you've done an exceedingly thorough job of proving that your own untested, obscure code is flawless. Note that "prove" is not an exact synonym for "assume", "hope", or "wish".

Comment: OK, so maybe buggy was wrong word. I meant that behavior of RenderTransform is unexpected. Any ideas whats wrong here? :)

Comment: Can you explain why you expected `"0.7071068 0.7071068 -0.7071068 0.7071068 323.4487 -228.8742"` to produce a different result?

Comment: I think it's reasonable to guess that the matrix transform in SVG doesn't have an exact correspondence with WPF's MatrixTransform, but the converter wrongly assumes otherwise. Perhaps one is applied before positioning, and the other after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MatrixTransform in WPF/XAML works slightly different than in SVG. The values are given in different order, and the transformation is relative to the current position. See [this article](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MatrixTransform.aspx) for details on the WPF matrix transform.

You copied the matrix values from SVG, which doesn't work. For example, you are moving your shape by 323 units to the right, which would make sense if it was located at (0,0). But here your shape is already placed at the right position, so you don't need to shift it further.

In SVG, the values are given column by column ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)). In WPF, the values are given row by row ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform(v=vs.110).aspx)).

A correct matrix transform could look like this (note the different order of values and the two zeroes in the transition part):

```
<Rectangle xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="323.4487" Canvas.Top="228.8742" Width="94" Height="84" Name="rect4" Fill="#00FFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#000000">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <MatrixTransform Matrix="0.7071068 -0.7071068 0.7071068 0.7071068 0 0"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```